# Browser automation With selenium python : unable to locate element for join now google meet

Tags: python, selenium, web, firefox, webautomation

i want to build an web automation program that automatically joins google meet using selenium with firefox driver in python.I was able to sign up,mute the mike and turn off camera,No problem till there,but iam having difficulty in pressing the join button,i cannot find the perfect element for join button...i have tried xpath,using classname,by text, nothing is working.is there any other method to get that join button to get clicked

Please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide your example code so I just assume that you might not have fluent wait?

It takes some time for the site to display "Join now" button. Try using this xpath: `//span[text()="Join now"]/..`. Change the text "Join now" to your language if needed.

Use fluent wait (actively search for the element in 10 seconds, only raise Exception after 10 seconds):

```py
xpath = '//span[text()="Join now"]/..'
join_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath)))
```

Comment: Thanks...it worked
you were right i wasnt using fluent wait..but i gave 10 sec of delay time before clicking the join button and still it didnt work.Dont know why. Anyway thank you very much

Comment: 10 sec delay is not really a good idea. Fluent wait is the best choice most of the time, so try to learn how to use it :). Clicking your button didn't work might be some of these problems: element not clickable yet, or you used the wrong locator. Try debugging your xpath using the Developer tool from Chrome/Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Try using actions:

```
 Actions action = new Actions(driver); 
 action.moveToElement(element);
        action.click();
        action.build().perform();
```

if not helping - maybe try by coordinates:

```
 action.move_to_element(elem).move_by_offset(x_offset, y_offset).click().perform()
```

Comment: thank you for your answer....but iam really sorry
i am using selenium with python and not java

Comment: It's almost the same:

        #Create the object for Action Chains
        actions = ActionChains(driver)
        actions.move_to_element(menu)
        # perform the operation on the element
        actions.perform()

Comment: Anyone having same prolem with java, will find it helpful...Thank you